# Create outlook folder loop via excel range

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-outlook-2016, vbscript, vb6

I could able to loop sender names from first columns of excel & nwow I am trying to create folder loop in below code but it showing error !!!

```
Sub MoveItems()
Dim myNameSpace As 
Outlook.Namespace

Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set myNameSpace =   Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI.   ")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderinbox)
Set myItems = myInbox.Items


Dim varSearchTerms As Variant
varSearchTerms = Range("a1:a3").Value 'refering to excel range for sender names

Dim varSearchTerm As Variant
For Each varSearchTerm In varSearchTerms

Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders(range("b2"b3").value)
       myItem.Move myDestFolder
     Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
  Wend
   Next

 End Sub
```

Its showing error at this stage

```
  Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
     While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders(range("b2"b3").value)
           myItem.Move myDestFolder
         Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
```

Can anyone suggest how should i do it ?

Comment: If you're in Outlook, where the hell is that `Range` supposed to come from? You would need to start with and Excel Application object so you could access an open workbook to get to a sheet that contains a range. So in Outlook, you're at least 4 steps away from being able to say `Range`

Comment: You also have a bunch of typos. This code wouldn't compile.

Comment: `Range("a1:a3").Value` is going to return a string. You cannot `For...Next` a string. If we remove `.Value` then you get a range object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry for that i am still learning VBA, this is very simple.code but i am not able to.do it 